# overflow-y overrides overflow-x

Tags: html, css

I need a `div` that has a lot of content and scrolls horizontally. The content (inner `div`s) has dropdown menus, and when the menus are opened they are supposed to render beyond the outer `div`'s borders.

Like so:

[image]

But when i set

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: visible;
```

my dropdowns aren't opened properly, they are contained within the wrapper `div` and I need to scroll down vertically to see them.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dk58t1ay/1/

It looks like `overflow-x:scroll` overrides `overflow-y:visible`. What can I do about it?

Comment: Please check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497373/make-content-horizontally-scroll-inside-a-div

Comment: I think you will have to use `position: absolute` on first card to do this https://jsfiddle.net/dk58t1ay/3/

Comment: @NenadVracar then this element stops scrolling horizontally. I need to sroll it with other elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via `position: absolute` to your `.card`, but you need to rewrite your styles for other elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/dk58t1ay/6/

Comment: then this element stops scrolling horizontally. I need to sroll it with other elements.

Comment: It doesn't scroll anymore because you need to rewrite styles for your inner elements, they positioned a little differ now.